# API Level 11 min is 9, what can I do to fix this

Tags: android, android-manifest, build-target

One of my classes has many errors because API level 11 (min is 9) is it better to fix it or change min. If so how do I fix it or how do I change min Im very new to this, also what is a good source to learn from with new-ish code

```
package com.ramos.science;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new       MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(com.ramos.science.R.xml.prefs);
}

}
}
```

Comment: If you look at the dashboard link I posted, it will tell you about all the different versions of Android. I also posted a link to supporting different versions.

Answer (score 3):

modify AndroidManifest.xml  file

add

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Comment: And what version of Android is sdk 11? Also whats a good place to learn how to code android?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels   api11 is android 3.0

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html has a lot of information about android programming

Answer (score 2):

It really just depends on what you want and who you are targeting. Since `Fragment` was introduced in `API 11`, if you want to use them then you should make your `minimum >= 11`. If you look at the **[DashBoard Docs](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)** you can see that the majority of devices which download apps from the Play Store are Gingerbread (`API 9`). If you want to reach the broadest amount of people then you may not want to use `Fragment`s but if you want to program for the future then I would suggest using a minimum of 11.

It really kind of depends on who you are targeting. But ICS has gained a lot of ground in the last 6 months or so. My recommendation would be to program for those newer devices because their slice is only going to get bigger. Unless, of course, you know that a lot of your users will have older devices

[Supporting different versions](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)

Comment: @Roylee thank you. Explaining answers on here go a lot further in learning than simply providing code

Answer (score 1):

Inside of class you can use Android annotations like so:

```
@TargetApi(11)
public void functionName() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In additional to what codeMagic has explained. This is an add-on resources for what you need: 
[What API level should I target](http://simonvt.net/2012/02/07/what-api-level-should-i-target/).

---

Besides I have difficulties when I first kick-started android, here's some really good android books for beginner:

1. [Pro Android 3](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9070205-pro-android-3) (Android developer would keep this in their bookshelf)
2. [Head First Android Development](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9625998-head-first-android-development) (It guides you by example)
3. [Learning Android](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9968133-learning-android?ac=1)
    (Perfect book to master your fundamentals)

---

To master the best android practices, learn from his code:
[yuriykulikov/AlarmClock](https://github.com/yuriykulikov/AlarmClock)

After all, I hoped it helps :) Good luck.